# Prove that D is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group, $T = G \times G$ and let $D = \{(g,g)\in G \times G | g\in G\}$. Prove that D is normal in T if and only if G is abelian.

I assume that D is normal in T, then for any $x,y \in T$ we have $(xgx^{-1}, ygy^{-1})$ for $g\in D.$ How can I show that $G$ is abelian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $D$ is normal, then $(xgx^{-1}, ygy^{-1}) \in D$ for every $x, y \in G$, that is, $xgx^{-1} = ygy^{-1}$. Take $y$ to be the identity element of $G$ and $x$ to be an arbitrary element of $G$.

Comment: If y is the identity then $xgx^{-1} = g$ which implies $xg = gx$.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I didn't know I can make y as an identity element. Made it a lot simpler! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $D$ is normal in $G$. Suppose $G$ is not abelian. Then there exist $x,y \in G$ such that $xy\neq yx$ and thus $yxy^{-1}\neq x$. Now $(x,y)(x,x)(x,y)^{-1}= (x,yxy^{-1}) \notin T$. Which show that $D$ is not normal in $G$. That a contradiction. So $G$ must be abelian.

The converse is easy.